# Unexpected windows button and VK_ESC key messages

Tags: windows, winapi, message-queue

I don't usually do much coding for Windows even though my development environment is in Windows. However I'm doing some work on an app. I am experiencing something rather unusual:

A second window is opened when the user clicks a particular button. The class is registered, window created and a few other things initialized. Everything seems to go without error except that after creation the window receives a WM_KEYDOWN for RWIN followed by WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP for VK_ESCAPE.

The VK_ESCAPE is tied to functionality to hide the window, so it appears and then hides because of these messages coming through after it is created.

I never touch the keyboard. The application is launched and interacted with the entire time using a mouse.

I have searched the codebase and inspected every SendMessage, PostMessage and related call. None of them are sending anything of the sort.

Furthermore the lParam for the WM_KEYUP message looks reasonable. So its highly unlikely to be an errant message that is completely different in nature. It is very much looking like an authentic keypress message.

So I have essentially two questions:

- Am I able to track where the message is being sent from?
- Is there some known mechanism by which keypress messages might be inserted into the message queue (other than the app itself calling SendMessage)?

EDIT:
For the WM_KEYUP message the values are:

lParam: 3221291009 or 1100 0000 0000 001 0000 0000 0000 001
wParam: 27

Which translates to:
repeat count: 1
scan code: 1
context code: 0
previous keystate: 1
transition state: 1

Comment: You can try the Spy++ utility that comes with most versions of VisualStudio to check if the window is really receiving these messages or is an artifact of your code. Also, can you post the exact `wParam/lParam` values of each message?

Comment: Anyway, you should probably use `WM_CHAR` to process the Escape key. Are you getting a `WM_CHAR` message too?

Comment: I once had a similar problem and ended up installing an API hook for keybd_event() and SendInput() to finally track down it was coming from a a utility installed by the OEM of my computer.  I would first try to run your program on a clean system (just a new Windows install, and nothing else) to see if the problem occurs, or if this is caused by some other software.

Comment: @rodrigo edited the question with the info. Thanks for the tip to try Spy++ - I'll do that after lunch. Also I confirmed that the WM_CHAR for the escape key comes through too.